How to Use Pre-Loaded Variables in RMarkdown Without Re-Executing the Script
I am currently working on a project in R where I need to generate reports using RMarkdown.
I have a primary R script, Reporte MKP.R, which loads and processes data into various variables and data frames.
How can I configure my RMarkdown file so that it uses the variables and data frames from the pre-executed Reporte MKP.R script without re-running the script every time I knit the document?
I've tried using the source() function within the RMarkdown setup chunk, but it re-executes the script, which is time-consuming. Is there a way to knit the RMarkdown document using the already available environment from my active R session?

A former colleague used to use save and load the entire workspace. However, this can create a real mess. I'd saveRDS each file you need, comment out the creating code and use readRDS when knitting.

I second this, you should save the output of the script and only load the results in the report, but another option is checking out how to cache chunk results, that way rendering the report should be way faster.

knitr allows to cache the results of code chunks using chunk option cache=TRUE, see e.g. https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cache.html#cache which as an alternative also mentions using saveRDS and readRDS as suggested by jay.sf.

Basically you need to cache your computation somehow. Either you take care of the caching your self, i.e. store the results or you use the builtin cahcing variant (or a little bit more sophisticated xfun::  equivalent:
---
title: "Caching"
author: "Me"
date: "2024-07-29"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r libs}
library(xfun)
library(here)
library(glue)
library(hms)
```

```{r simulate-long-running-process}
lengthy_data_getter <- function() {
  Sys.sleep(20)
  rnorm(1)
}
```

```{r consts-fns}
start <- Sys.time()
cache_manual_fn <- here("cache_manual.rds")
cache_xfun_fn <- here("cache_xfun.rds")

format_results <- function(res, start) {
  glue("Result: {res} retrieved in [{as_hms(round(Sys.time() - start, 1))}]")
}
```


# Cache Yourself

If the cache file does not yet exist, we create it, in subsequent runs it simply reads the 
contents from cache and renders much faster.

```{r manual-cache}
if (!file.exists(cache_manual_fn)) {
  res <- lengthy_data_getter()
  saveRDS(res, cache_manual_fn)
}
res <- readRDS(cache_manual_fn)
msg <- format_results(res, start)
start <- Sys.time()
msg
```

# Builtin Cache

Let `rmarkdown` do the caching (cf. 
[cahcing chapther in the Rmarkdown Cookbok](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cache.html))

```{r builtin-cache, cache = TRUE}
res <- lengthy_data_getter()
```

```{r time-builtin}
msg <- format_results(res, start)
start <- Sys.time()
msg
```

# `xfun::cache_rds`

Same as before, but more control over certain aspects of the cache file.

```{r xfun-cache}
res <- cache_rds(
  {
    lengthy_data_getter()
  },
  file = basename(cache_xfun_fn),
  dir = dirname(cache_xfun_fn)
)

msg <- format_results(res, start)
start <- Sys.time()
msg
```

The first run of the document shows the following:

While subsequent runs load the data almost instantly:

I'd personally go for the xfun solution, as it allows for finer control about when the cache should be invalidated. The manual verison is the worst solution here, b/c you have to remember to delete the cache file yourself in case you want ot invalidate it later.
The other 2 solutions are at least intelligent enough to recognize when the code generating the cache changes to automatically rerun the code. And the xfun solution allows even more sophistication to invalidate the cache when for instance the data* generating the results changes.
However, you have to be careful to not work with stale data accidently and always remember this famous quote:

There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation
and naming things.
-- Phil Karlton

